# React JSX, how to render text with a single quote? Example <p>I've</p>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React JSX how can I have the following text include a single quote? Or other punctuation that might need escaping?

```
 return (<p>I've seen the movie.</p>)
```

Comment: Use `@apos;` entity?

Comment: you mean `&apos;` ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Render as a JS string literal (with double-quotes):

```
return (<p>{"I've seen the movie."}</p>)
```

... or use the HTML entity for an apostrophe, `&apos;`:

```
return (<p>I&apos;ve seen the movie.</p>)
```

Comment: It's a shame that ES-Lint flags this as `Strings must use singlequote (quotes)`.

Comment: I like this answer better than the HTML entity replacement.

Comment: > `&apos;` is not a valid HTML character entity reference. It is an XML character entity reference. While Firefox and Chrome, at least, will render the above as an apostrophe in an HTML document, Internet Explorer will not. 
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/should-i-escape-the-apostrophe-character-with-its-html-entity-39

Comment: Why not just:

I've seen the movie.

Comment: Is this really needed, in presence of a modern bundler? Writing long text quickly become very annoying when each quote needs to be replaced

Answer (score 18):

Nevermind, it works as is.

It was the IDE that was highlighting it as a mistake

Comment: I think the other answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: I'm using tree-sitter on neovim, but this still happens today. I'd like to know if anyone has a workaround.

Answer (score 14):

You can use &quot html entity to have quote in your text.

```
<Text>I&quot;ve seen the movie.</Text>
```

output: I"ve seen the movie.

or if want single quot use the below option:

> ```
> <Text> I&apos;ve seen the movie.</Text>
>
> <Text>{'I\'ve seen the movie.'}</Text>
> {/* you can use both ticks and single quotes depending on your use. */}
> <Text>{`I've seen the movie.`}</Text>
> ```

output: I've seen the movie.

Comment: Good to see that `&apos;` was added in HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great reason to use the backtick (`` ` ``) for strings where it makes sense.

The text in the original question will work fine even though the syntax highlighting is off, but by also moving strings to a constant you can avoid worrying about escaping, highlighting and they're easier to find/update.

`` const TEXT_FOR_MOVIE = `Some text that's "quoted"` ``

const TEXT_FOR_MOVIE = `Some text that's "quoted"`

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to show a variable with quotes you can use this it will show quote and also display the value of the variable

```
{`"${variable}"`}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a "" in front of your apostrophe.

code:
**"I can't reach it'**

output:

**I can't reach it**