# Display apostrophe in jsx, React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am working on a react app and stuck over how to display apostrophe in jsx. I have some text which should come with apostrophe but its coming with code.

**What I need is :** This is ashwani`s app

**How its coming is :**  `This is ashwani&apos;s app'`

**What I am using is :** `tittle = 'This is ashwani&apos;s app'`

**I also tried :** `'This is ashwani${'&apos;'}s app'`

But nothing is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React JSX, how to render text with a single quote? Example <p>I've</p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979512/react-jsx-how-to-render-text-with-a-single-quote-example-pive-p)

Comment: by saying **How its coming** what do you mean is it you're getting this string like this and you want to change it to just apostrphe ?

Comment: @Ashwani did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic solution that handles all these HTML entities without having to statically create a map in order to reference each entity every time.

```js
const p = "This is ashwani&apos;s app'";

console.log(p.replace(/&([a-z]{1,4});/gi, match => new DOMParser().parseFromString(match, "text/html").documentElement.textContent));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the title (from API , database ....) like this `This is ashwani&apos;s app`  and you want it to be like this  `This is ashwani`s app` you can simply use **.replace** method
example :

```
  const title = "This is ashwani&apos;s app".replace("&apos;", "'");
```